# What is the least inaccessible cardinal for Tarski-Grothendieck set theory?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Let ordinal $\alpha$ be the least ordinal such that $V_\alpha\models$ Tarski-Grothendieck set theory.

What position does $\alpha$ have in the hierarchy of inaccessible cardinals?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*I missed the inaccessibility requirement initially - fixed!*

Since $\mathsf{TG}$ is "just" $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "There is a proper class of inaccessible cardinals," an inaccessible $\alpha$ satisfies $V_\alpha\models\mathsf{TG}$ iff $\alpha$ is an inaccessible limit of inaccessibles, i.e. a $1$-inaccessible.

That said, if we just ask for $V_\alpha\models\mathsf{TG}$ (that is, we don't demand that $\alpha$ be inaccessible), we can do significantly better: in this case, the relevant $\alpha$ is the smallest *worldly* limit of inaccessibles. This is bigger than the smallest limit of inaccessibles, but smaller than the smallest $1$-inaccessible.

Recall that $\alpha$ is worldly iff $V_\alpha\models\mathsf{ZFC}$. Generally, the smallest worldly $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha\models T$ (for any fixed $T$) has countable cofinality by a Lowenheim-Skolem type argument, and this is why the ordinal of the previous paragraph falls short of being $1$-inaccessible (= regular limit of inaccessible cardinals).

In a comment, the OP asks which is a better "gauge" (of strength presumably). I think there is no single answer; which cardinal you look at depends on precisely which sorts of questions you are asking. Sometimes it will make sense to include regularity as a core hypothesis, while other times it won't.

Comment: What are some well-known inaccessible cardinals smaller than the wordily limit of inaccessible cardinals?

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal I'm not really sure how to answer that.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal The second inaccessible cardinal?

Comment: @HanulJeon Very much higher. Tarski Grothendieck set theory has as many inaccessible cardinal as the ordinals it has in its class of ordinals. So Tarski-Grothendieck set theory has a class of distinct inaccessible cardinals.

Comment: @NoahSchweber My take is now, from your answer, combined with 

https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Inaccessible#Degrees_of_inaccessibility,

that the $\alpha$ in the question is a 1-$\mathrm{inaccessible}$ cardinal. 
May that be true? ... But you stated that is bigger than the smallest limit of inaccessible cardinals.  (｡·  v  ·｡)

Comment: @HanulJeon Aha. Yes, that is a well known inaccessible cardinal. :)

Comment: @FarmerS Indeed, fixed!

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal No, this $\alpha$ is not inaccessible - it isn't *regular*.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Aha!

Comment: @Nevertheless, there are plenty of inaccessible cardinals below $\alpha$, i.e. "the smallest worldly limit of inaccessibles".

Comment: The answer to the question as I posed it, "What is the least inaccessible cardinal for Tarski-Grothendieck set theory?", then, should be the least 1-inaccessible cardinal. However, should we think that a 1-inaccessible cardinals  is a better gauge than the worldly limit of inaccessible cardinal, or vice versa?

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal Whoops, good catch; see my edit. Note that your title is different from the question body, which doesn't assume inaccessibility.

Comment: @FarmerS GAAAAAH. Fixed, I hope.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Many thanks for your edit! :) The question I intended to pose, I believe, was: "Let   be the least regular cardinal such that
Vα⊨Tarski-Grothendieck set theory. What position does  have in the hierarchy of inaccessible cardinals?"

Comment: @NoahSchweber Many thanks for your edit! :) The question I intended to pose, I believe, was: "Let   be the least regular cardinal such that
Vα⊨Tarski-Grothendieck set theory. What position does  have in the hierarchy of inaccessible cardinals?" I think I believe this, as  I believe that it is most common to characterize a set theory ST in terms of the least inaccessible $\kappa$ such that $\mathrm{V}_\kappa\models ST.$